# SWT get cursor position

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, swt

I'm making a simple "paint" application in JAVA.
I would have wanted that when the person clicks the canvas, and make a drag and drop the listener of the drag gets the position of the cursor and also for the drop.
(I'm using Eclipse)

I have this code :

```
Canvas paintC = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
paintC.addDragDetectListener(new DragDetectListener() {
    public void dragDetected(DragDetectEvent arg0) {            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` and `y` fields of `DragDetectEvent` contain the position (relative to the `Canvas`)

```
Point controlRelativePos = new Point(arg0.x, arg0.y);

Point displayRelativePos = paintC.toDisplay(controlRelativePos);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm really bad in Java programming. I've got the following error on arg0 : "arg0 cannot be resolved to a variable" I don't know why this happen. It's the first time i use it EDIT : Ok I've done a mistake, there is no error. I'm trying your solution thank you